# Is a snake's venom poisonous (or venomous)?

Tags: meaning, differences, adjectives, word-usage

This is a question more concerning the word *poisonous* and *venomous* than *poison* vs. *venom.*

I'm wondering about the following, specifically the last sentence:

- Don't eat the plant, it is **poisonous**.
- The plant has dripped poison onto you. Be careful, the liquid is **poisonous**.
- The snake is **venomous**.
- The snake has been milked to help us create an antidote. Be careful, the contents of the jar are **poisonous** (or should it be **venomous**?).

Can you use *poisonous* and *venomous* to describe both the creature/plant AND the substance it produces?

Comment: Its interesting to note that you [can "safely" drink most if not all snake venoms without adverse effects](http://ufwildlife.ifas.ufl.edu/venomous_snake_faqs.shtml) so long as you have no cuts in your mouth etc **Do not try this at home**. I have always taken that to be the difference between poison and venom

Comment: "I wanna taste you, but your lips are venomous poison..."

Comment: [***venomous:*** (Of animals, especially snakes, or their parts) secreting venom; capable of injecting venom by means of a bite or sting. ***venom:*** A poisonous substance secreted by animals such as snakes, spiders, and scorpions and typically injected into prey or aggressors by biting or stinging. ***poisonous***: (Of a substance or plant) causing or capable of causing death or illness if taken into the body. (Of an animal) producing poison as a means of attacking enemies or prey.](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com)

Comment: See also [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/515389/what-is-the-justification-for-the-difference-between-venom-and-poison/515405), [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8686/what-is-the-difference-between-venom-and-poison/127236), and [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/511182/toxicity-venomous-and-poison) for other SE discussions of the poison/venom/toxin distinction.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> **Poison is absorbed or ingested**; a poisonous animal can only deliver toxic chemicals if another animal touches or eats it.
>
> Venom, on the other hand, **is always injected**. Every venomous
>   animal has a mechanism to inject toxins directly into another animal.
>   Stab with tails. Slash with spines. Pierce with fangs or stings. Spike
>   with spurs. Shoot with harpoons. Chew with teeth.-http://www.diffen.com/difference/Poison_vs_Venom

- Don't eat the plant, it is **poisonous**. -correct
- The plant has **dripped poison** onto you. Be careful, the liquid is poisonous. -correct
- The snake is venomous. -correct
- The snake has been milked to help us create an antidote. Be careful, the contents of the jar are poisonous. -correct and not venomous

> What is the difference between poison and venom? If you drink venom,
>   will it kill you?
>
> skull and cross bones: poison are substances that are toxic (cause
>   harm) if swallowed or inhaled. Venoms are generally not toxic if
>   swallowed, and must be injected under the skin (by snakes, spiders,
>   etc.) into the tissues that are normally protected by skin in order to
>   be toxic. However, we do NOT recommend drinking venom!
>   -http://ufwildlife.ifas.ufl.edu/venomous_snake_faqs.shtml

Comment: The last point though, presumably drinking the venom wouldn't have any effect (since it must be injected) so is it really poisonous?

Comment: That is an interesting point but I think it depends on the toxicity.

Comment: What about a blade coated with a substance? Would that be venom or poison?

Comment: Technically, mechanically introducing the venom (envenoming) into the bloodstream has the same effect...I need to consult!

Comment: Medically, the consequences of a venomous contact are termed 'local effects'(tissue area) and 'systemic effects' local effects'(blood vessels/lymph vessels.  If the venom is introduced otherwise, or the tainted knife, it still has the same pathology.

Comment: This may be a case of an 'exception that proves the rule' but there is a species that can spit venom.  The spitting cobras envenoming through biting, but also "project venom at a potential threat. The venom is an irritant to the skin and eyes. If it enters the eyes, symptoms include extreme burning pain, loss of coordination, partial loss of vision and permanent blindness."  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-necked_spitting_cobra)

Comment: I'm not sure if this sublates, or medical interpretation(moderate cytotoxic effects)differs from an ophiological definition. Also, an ophiologist may know if the conflict is due to the discovery of the species distinction post 1820

Comment: @SLC: A venom **can** also be poisonous (or if it was a venom that attacked blood could potentially get to the vascular system via ulcers in your stomach etc.). So probably not a good idea to drink venom.

Comment: @Lori astari, a tooth cavity too

Comment: @ThirdNews It's a fringe case: The venom is being actively shot into the eyes, which are here being taken as 'inside' the first layer of bodily defenses (under the eyelids). Mostly, it's an overprecious distinction that helps with clarity in some contexts but really is just a vestigial remnant of early English getting 2 separate words to describe _thing I put in my husband's food_ and _thing the snake injected into my son_.

Comment: [Here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/515416/171986) Mr Shor explains that, even though _venom_ comes from the Latin word for _poison_ or [_quack medicine_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mithridate) and _poison_ come from the word for _quack medicine_ and should mostly overlap, the French started making a sharp distinction in the early modern era and English seems to have gradually picked up on it.

Answer (score 18):

By definition, venomous (in your sense of the word) describes an **animal** capable if injecting a poison (although my experience with stinging nettles may cause me to define it differently). Some venomous animals include spiders, bees, scorpions, jellyfish, some spiny fish, and the blue-ringed octopus.

> [*venomous*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/venomous): (of an animal) having a gland or glands for secreting venom; able to inflict a poisonous bite or sting.

Therefore, venom (the secretory product) cannot be venomous.

**Poison, however, is poisonous**. Poisonous describes its *potential effect on the body*. Some poisonous animals include puffer fish, monarch butterflies, birds who feed on poisonous insects, etc. Poisonous plants make poison, but unless it is ingested (has an effect on the body), it does not act as a poison. If it is a skin irritant, I'd say it was a topical irritant. (Maybe too specific for you.)

> [*Poisonous*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/poisonous): (Medicine) having the effects or qualities of a poison; (of a substance or plant) causing or capable of causing death or illness if taken into the body (usually by ingestion or inhalation).

Informally, *poisonous snake* is synonymous with *venomous snake*. However, not all poisonous animals are venomous (poison dart frogs secrete a toxin which is one of the strongest poisons produced by an animal.) It is sometimes called a venom, but doesn't fit the usual definition of venom. It becomes a venom when used on dart-tips.

Edited to clarify and add: some venoms are poisonous if swallowed, but most are not. Snake venom is usually harmless if swallowed, but poison dart frogs are poisonous if swallowed.

I would say, vemon *can* be poisonous, but venom can't be venomous.

Comment: This answer seems to make a muddled distinction between animals and non-animals. Some animals are venomous (some snakes, some spiders) but some animals are poisonous (some frogs, Some fish). The puffer-fish is poisonous, the stonefish is venomous.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick - you're correct. But I will incorporate this into my answer if it will clarify.

Comment: The first bit about venom is just wrong. What you included was _a_ sense of the word venomous but not [_all_ senses of the word venomous](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/222192). Venom the secretory product absolutely can be described as like-venom venomous even if it isn't has/uses-venom venomous.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick is correct that the edited answer still wrongly pretends poisonous plants need to be injested. They don't. You can call it a topical irritant so as to communicate the level of necessary caution effectively, but the substance itself is still a poison that is taken into the body upon contact with the skin.

Comment: Similarly, poison used on a sword doesn't become a venom (except in flowery poetry) just because you're going to introduce it into your opponent's body in the manner of actual venom. The sword isn't part of your natural secretions or body, howevermuch you train until it feels like an extension of your arm.

Comment: Theoretically, in some environments, there might be mold or some other toxic substance that generally grows on nails that could render people who live in that environment actually venomous, but that would really be straining the definition and leaning very hard into the people-are-_just_-animals trope that doesn't match how most language handles things.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

> [venom](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/venom) (1): poisonous matter normally secreted by some animals (as snakes, scorpions, or bees) and transmitted to prey or an enemy chiefly by biting or stinging; broadly :  material that is poisonous

Comment: In general use, yeah, but you're only answering the title question. The answer to the question in the post requires a longer answer than "yes" or its brief answer is "no".

Comment: Feel free and answer then.

Comment: We include comments to help posters improve their answers. Anyway, you've seen it.

Answer (score 0):

Roughly, a *poisonous* animal (or plant, or anything else) is one which will have toxic effects on you if you eat it; a *venomous* animal is one that is capable of injecting poison into you, e.g., by biting or stinging. Thus, it is possible for an animal to be neither poisonous nor venomous, poisonous but not venomous, venomous but not poisonous (assuming you don't eat the glands that produce the venom) or both venomous and poisonous.

[According to QI](http://old.qi.com/talk/viewtopic.php?t=11751&start=0&sid=9a1120c6a64456fb0a5f4a0e590300f5), the only *poisonous* snakes are the Japanese grass snake and the common garter snake.

Comment: QI is a joy to watch but never a reliable source for anything except putdowns and one-liners. Garter snakes are not poisonous at all, although they have a venom too weak to affect most humans. There are other snakes that are not necessarily poisonous but habitually eat other animals who are not poisonous to the snakes but would be poisonous to humans who caught and ate the snake at the wrong phase in the digestive cycle.

Answer (score -1):

Venomous creatures and poisonous creatures both produce at least one substance that is *toxic.*

However, for a toxin-producing creature to itself be classed as toxic, it would have to be ingested, or else handled in such a way that its toxin was absorbed through the skin.

Comment: I don't understand your second paragraph. You seem to be saying that something is only "toxic" if it has actually caused harm: by your argument, it seems that a pile of arsenic is non-toxic but, if somebody eats some of that arsenic, the arsenic within them *is* toxic. That is not how the word is used.

Comment: @David Richerby - I see how you could logically infer what you assert, but in the context of this discussion that interpretation makes no sense.

Comment: I genuinely can't tell what you're trying to say. If something produces toxins, it is toxic. And why are you explaining when a creature would be described as "toxic" anyway? The question is about the distinction between venomous and poisonous.

Comment: This answer mixes up the meaning of _toxic_ and the over-precise sense of _poisonous_ used by some scientists and _many_ middle school biology teachers. Venomous and poisonous creatures both produce toxins. The venom is toxic. The poison is toxic. In general use, toxins and poisons are synonymous. In rigorous jargon, poisons are properly able to be readily passively absorbed and, in practice, are the toxins not otherwise labeled as venoms, which require active injection. No creature is toxic, aside from ones like microorganisms that can be completely readily absorbed whole, but any toxins are.