# Difference between toxic and poisonous?

Tags: differences

Could you please tell the difference between toxic and poisonous with examples?

For example the smoke of the factories, cigars and the substance in the cans such as tuna fish which make us boil it before serving it. Which of them are toxic and which of them are poisonous?

Thank you so much

Comment: Have you compared dictionary definitions? The [OED entry for toxic](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/toxic) says "Origin Mid 17th century: from medieval Latin toxicus ‘poisoned’, from Latin toxicum ‘poison’, from Greek toxikon (pharmakon) ‘(poison for) arrows’, from toxon ‘bow’.

Comment: @weather your link is not to the OED but to the ODO (Oxford online dictionary). The OED requires a subscription to access.

Comment: I agree, however, that the OP can use the ODO to look up both words for the definitions and example sentences, thus this question should be closed due to lack of research.

Comment: Yes I checked the dictionaries. But my examples which I have written are not in them and somehow I got confused. If there is a native person who can answer it simply that would be great

Comment: Somewhat similar: [Is a snake's venom poisonous (or venomous)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/170388)

Comment: Hi David, if you're learning English you might be interested in [the sister site for English language learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/). I'm answering this question because I think it's a good candidate for migrating to ELL.

Comment: @Race do we have to answer a Q before it can be migrated?

Comment: @Clare no, I just wanted to explain why I was answering the question even though I don't think it belongs on EL&U

Comment: @Race all right, just not sure that would be my approach but whatever. Nice answer  at any rate.

Answer (score 1):

In many cases, when referring to a substance that is harmful, the words can be used interchangeably.  The definitions provided in most dictionaries include senses that overlap quite a bit.  For example, the *OED* provides these definitions for each as the primary sense:

> **Toxic**: 1. Of the nature of a poison; poisonous.
>
> **Poisonous**:  1. Containing, or of the nature of, poison; having the properties of a poison; venomous.

So there are many cases where either word could be used.

> The factory produced **toxic** gasses that were released into the atmosphere

means essentially the same thing as

> The factory produced **poisonous** gasses that were released into the atmosphere.

In both cases, the implication is that the gasses could cause harm to humans or the environment.

But as with many synonyms, there are alternate senses for each word that don't work interchangeably, and slight variations in the way the words are used that make them subtly different.

For instance, consider "poisonous" used to mean "venomous."

> Some snake bites are from nonpoisonous snakes, but 20-30% of the bites from **poisonous snakes** do not actually inject poison into the wound

- [*The New York Times*, 2006](http://www.nytimes.com/health/guides/poison/snake-bite-poison/overview.html?mcubz=3)

One would not usually refer to a venomous organism as "toxic," but the word "poisonous" is used to mean *venomous* enough that it is included in the first sense of the word as defined in *OED*.

On the other hand, there are cases where the word "toxic" is used in extended figurative uses that would not be interchangeable with "poisonous."

> Mike Cagney, chief executive of SoFi, was accused of contributing to a **toxic workplace culture**.

- [*The New York Times*, 2017](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/09/12/technology/sofi-chief-executive-toxic-workplace.html)

Here, "toxic" is being figuratively extended to mean that the workplace culture grew damaging and harmful to people involved, though not literally "poisonous."

Comment: Good answer. In the most technical sense a toxin is always a natural substance produced by a living organism. A poison may be natural or man-made. A venom is a toxin that's injected. But most uses of these terms are not that technical.

Comment: Thank you Jim and specialy Race. I really appreciate your answers