# Are stingrays' barbs poisonous of venomous?

Tags: differences

I understand that when a snake bites you and you die, it's venom, and when you bite a snake and you die, it's poison.  What about stingrays' barbs? They don't bite you, they kind of shoot at you, but you don't bite them either.

At first I thought it would be poisonous, because it's outside of it's body and it doesn't bite you. The poison is kind of injected.

Then I thought it's venom, because the animal itself makes an effort to attack you with it.

So, are stingrays poisonous or venomous?

Comment: The poison/venom distinction does not hinge on actual biting, but on how the substance is introduced into the system in general: ingestion/absorption vs injection. Stingray barbs inject themselves and enter the bloodstream directly and subcutaneously; they are not ingested (eaten) or absorbed (by simply touching your skin). Hence, they are venomous, not poisonous. See the answers to [Is a snake’s venom poisonous (or venomous)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/170388) (of which this is really a duplicate, just with a different animal) for more details.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I agree with that distinction but the use of the words is quite loose. For instance curare-dipped darts are almost universally referred to a "poison darts" even though curare has to pass directly into the blood before it has any effect, which is why game hunted with curare darts is safe to eat.